# How to publish a virtual directory over IIS or XAMPP?

Tags: iis, deployment, virtual-directory

I have a virtual directory that points to a virtual drive on sql server. I need this directory to be accessible over the Internet, how do I do that? I've tried adding a virtual directory to default IIS website
[image]
When navigating over to localhost/magentofiles this is what I get.
[image]

Of course it cannot find web.config...it's a directory not a project I'm trying to publish. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it didn't really matter whether to use IIS or XAMPP, I went with XAMPP because I could not solve the errors of IIS. Now here's how to publish a directory over xampp.

- Create a directory in xampp/htdocs (let's say "files")
- In cmd go to that new directory.
- use [mklink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) to create a symbolic link to your desired destination (let's say "images")

open up xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf and at the bottom of the file append this code

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\files"

    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\files">
        Options FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

- Restart apache

You should be able to access files in that directory over localhost/images/example.png

Also note that the user, which xampp runs by should have access to the destination that you are publishing, otherwise you will get 403 Access forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for this error, you can try the following methods to solve the problem:

1. Right-click the website in your iis, then select Explore, check the current project folder if there is a web.config file, if there is then right click your web.config, expand properties, and under security tab, add IIS_IUSRS. Give the group read/write permissions.
2. Right-click the application pool of your current project, select Advanced Settings, and then change the Identity to LocalSystem.
3. Adding the IIS_IUSRS with read/write permissions to C:\inetpub\wwwroot.

Comment: I ended up using xampp. Created a symlink with windows mklink command in xampp's htdocs folder and then created a vhost pointing to that directory.

Comment: Is your problem solved? If it is solved, please share your answer and accept it so that it can help more people solve the same problem.